# Regex for currency - Exclude commas from the count limit

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I am using the following regex in my app:

`^(([0-9|(\\,)]{0,10})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`

So it allows 10 characters before the decimal and 2 character after it.
But I am inserting one additional functionality of formatting textfield as currency while typing. So if I have `1234567` it becomes `1,234,567` after formatting. The regex fails when I enter 10 characters instead of 10 digits. Ideally it should be that regex ignores the commas when counting 10.

I tried this too `^(([0-9|(\\,)]{0,13})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` but it doesn't seem the right approach. 
Can anyone help me get a proper regex instead of using this tweak.

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow any amount of commas in the integer part? Something like `"^((?:,*[0-9]){0,10})?(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"`?

Comment: Please check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Sb8wJQ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, it works like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Off topic but only allowing 2 decimals for currency rates is very limiting and you might get rates showing as 0.00 depending on in what way the currency is represented, i.e ABC/DEF vs DEF/ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"^(?:,*[0-9]){0,10}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

Or, if there must be a digit after `.` in the fractional part use

```
"^(?:,*[0-9]){0,10}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sb8wJQ/2/). The `(?:,*[0-9]){0,10}` part is what does the job: it matches any 0+ `,` chars followed with a single digit 0 to 10 times. If `,` can also appear before `.`, add `,*` after the `((?:,*[0-9]){0,10})?`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:,*[0-9]){0,10}` - 0 to 10 occurrences of 0+ commas followed with a digit
- `(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\.` - a period
  - `[0-9]{0,2}` - 0 to 2 digits (if there must be a digit after `.` use `[0-9]{1,2}`)
- `$`  - end of string.